# W/OpenGLRenderer: Incorrectly called buildLayer on View: ImageButton, destroying layer

Tags: android

I have a simple app, in which the main activity shows a fragment when you click on a button in the main UI. The fragment shows correctly the first time. After you dismiss the fragment (or hide it), it can't be shown the second time and since then. I always see this message in the logcat:

> W/OpenGLRenderer: Incorrectly called buildLayer on View: ImageButton, destroying layer...

Can anyone shed some light on this issue? Where might be the problem? I can't see much on SO or Google regarding this issue.